# Prevent focus in input elements not in dialog when dialog is visible in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have implemented dialog in html.

What i want is ::

In my dialog, there is a form with form elements.
   There is another form in main page beneath dialog.

Now, when i pressing tab, cursor is moving to each form elements including elements beneath dialog.

I just want to restrict tab in form elements beneath dialog.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it by attribute `tabIndex`

Let's say your new form have three input box

```
<input type="text" tabIndex="31" name="inp1" id="inp1">
<input type="text" tabIndex="32" name="inp2" id="inp2">
<input type="text" tabIndex="33" name="inp3" id="inp3" onBlur="tabIndexToFirst()">
```

Now when you reach to the last form element and press tab you need to jump to the first form element of that form.

**JS**:

```
function showNewForm() {
 document.getElelmentById('inp1').focus();
}
function tabIndexToFirst() {
 document.getElelmentById('inp1').focus();
}
```